# What's difference between ContentStyle, StyleClass and InlineStyle in ADF?

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Can you tell what's difference between `Content Style`, `Style Class` and `Inline Style` in ADF?

Comment: what did you have researched so far? which part of the concepts you didnt understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog can help you understand a bit about it:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adf_faces_skin_editor_how
Content is the content of a field
Styleclass - refers to a class in the CSS
inline style - change directly in page